# Cocos2d-x :Fade in list of items by sequence with different location

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm newbie in Coco2d-x

I have a list of items (could be text)
I want to display them by sequence, one by one per 1 second in different location.
For example i have an array  like items[50]
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is a place to look for help rather than full answers (generally). Have you look at Actions (http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Actions)? Especially `FadeIn` should be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have pasted few code below to show you how ccsequence works

```
CCFadeIn * fadeInText = CCFadeIn::create;
CCDelayTime * Delay = CCDelayTime::create(0.5f);
CCFadeIn * fadeInText2 = CCFadeIn::create;
CCCallFunc * funGame = CCCallFunc::create(this,callfunc_selector(HelloWorld::funcGame));
CCSequence *Sequence = CCSequence::create(fadeInText, readyDelay, fadeInText2, funGame, NULL);
myObject->runAction(Sequence);
```

Comment: How it is defined that `fadeInText` and `fadeInText2` fade different texts if it is in the same sequence and you apply that on `myObject`?